# A novel involving philosophy and hyperspace, ca. pre-1990

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, hyperspace

I am trying to remember the title of a novel with the following plot points:

1. A spacecraft is sent via supposedly instantaneous travel to a distant system, but they return 1,000 or 2,000 years later (this is the backstory, it's outlined at the beginning). They thought they were getting a hyperdrive; they really just got a sort-of-relativistic one.
2. The planet they travel to is inhabited by a race of furry beings who are "primitive" but have a philosophical outlook that allowed the humans to improve their pseudo-hyperdrive
3. When the explorers return there's some political intrigue involving the people of Earth
4. I recall a line from the book where the explorers are talking with a dude who is their orientation officer of sorts, and he says that "well, yes, we've discovered everything" about physics, or something like
5. I think the author was one of the bigger names but I can't recall

This mayn't be much to go on. But I can describe the cover: it had one of the furry beings on it, looking like a werewolf or something, in the corridor of a spacecraft.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Poul Anderson  *No World Of Their Own*. The furry alien fits

> The Holatan made no answer. His huge sleek-furred body was motionless in the acceleration couch they  had jury rigged for him

As does the situation

> “There was an adequate theory” said Langley. According to it the ship warped through hyperspace.” - - “There’s no such animal  - - according to an external observer, the trip is still made only at the speed of light - -“

And Anderson was certainly a Big Name. One of my old favourites and I still miss him seventeen years since he passed on.

Comment: YES! Thanks very much. I just looked it up and that's the one.

Comment: Also I discovered that it got published under the title "The Long Way Home" which is how I encountered it years back: https://www.tor.com/2012/10/05/oops-wrong-spacedrive-poul-andersons-the-long-way-home/